Dryer vent damper
https://imgur.com/a/HJhWdps
Hi there. I feel like there’s an easy answer to this question and I’m just dumb. My dad passed away recently and I’m trying to take care of our home but I don’t know what I’m doing.
I can’t remember us ever cleaning out our dryer vent so I bought one of those long, flexible brushes and stuck it in the exhaust. I immediately knocked out what I think is the damper and for the life of me cannot figure out how to put it back. I took pictures of the inside and there are little hooks that line up with the holes of this metal plate (the damper, I think), but one hook isn’t open so I can’t hang the plate off of it, and the plate immediately falls off when I hang it from the other hook.
I am going to try to attach pictures. Any guidance is really appreciated. Thank you.

Should be able to bend the tab open enough to place the damper back on.  bend both tabs close again, just enough to hold the damper but let it move.  If the tabs break off(old age), just get a new one.  They should be only a few dollars.

First, you'll want to clean out all the rest of the lint that is still stuck in there. An old toothbrush will work wonders. Get a small slotted screwdriver and open the tab on the left just enough to allow the damper to be hooked back on. Force the tab on the right up enough to hold the damper in place. A small mirror, makeup compact, might help in seeing what's up there while you're working on it. When finished, the damper should move back and forth freely.
